# Cannot fully install hwe stack on 18.04.2

Tags: kernel

I just tried to install the HWE stack using `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`, but it does not fully install. There is no boot image generated, nothing is loaded in `/lib/modules` for it, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Output of install command:

```bsh
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/15.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 248 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic-hwe-18.04.
(Reading database ... 407048 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic-hwe-18.04_4.18.0.15.65_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (4.18.0.15.65) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04.
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04_1%3a7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2) ...
Setting up linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (4.18.0.15.65) ...
```

Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux my-computer-name 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of attempting to manually install two apparently missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
[sudo] password for brandon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (4.18.0.15.65).
linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 set to manually installed.
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (4.18.0.15.65).
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

```
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic                   4.15.0-20.21                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic                   4.15.0-45.48                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic                   4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                             4.15.0.45.47                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04                   4.18.0.15.65                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Output of `sudo update-grub`

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

[This laptop came preinstalled with Windows and used to run it, hence the WBM entry.]

Error when trying to manually reinstall image:

```
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Please run this command and add the result to your question. And also post output of `uname -a`.

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: It is not the full output. But if there were no errors, reboot now, and you will be on the 4.18 kernel. But I don't see real kernel modules installed.

Comment: ...except that is the full output. There were no messages about installing boot images like I expected. After rebooting I'm still on the 4.15 kernel, and the only "advanced" boot options are to boot into that 4.15 kernel or the accompanying recovery mode.

Comment: This is a mystery `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` depends on `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04` and `linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04`. But I don't see them installed. Something is broken in your system.

Comment: Well, duh. That's why I posted here! Also, I just added the output of trying to manually install those dependencies. It seems that they're already installed.

Comment: Post output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

Comment: Can you boot to 4.18 using grub menu?

Comment: Output added. Cannot boot into 4.18 through the GRUB menu; I only see 4.15

Comment: The 4.18 kernel is installed.

Comment: Please post output of `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: But I cannot boot into it, so it's useless to me then. I can only boot into 4.15. Is there a way to purge this out and attempt to reinstall it so the boot images are also generated?

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic`

Comment: Error produced:
```
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Now it's clear what is the problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reinstall this kernel and modules with low-level commands (download and direct extract to the file-system):

```
apt-get download linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic
apt-get download linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic
apt-get download linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic
apt-get download linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic

sudo dpkg -x linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic*.deb /
sudo dpkg -x linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic*.deb /
sudo dpkg -x linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic*.deb /
sudo dpkg -x linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic*.deb /

sudo update-grub
```

then reinstall them with regular way:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic
```

and finally install the HWE:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: Why would I need to also install the 4.15.0-20 kernel when I'm currently running the 4.15.0-45 kernel?

Comment: @Brandon thanks, it was a typo. You need 4.18.0-15.

Comment: Is it normal for "Processing triggers for linux-image-*" to take forever to complete? It's been quite a while, and looking at htop it seems like nothing's happening.
EDIT: Also is reporting that these processes are sleeping, not running.

Comment: It is not normal. I have never seen such behavior. Are you sure that your filesystem is clean? Try to force fsck with `sudo touch /forcefsck` and reboot.

Comment: fsck seems to have ran with no issue. Same behavior is being experienced the second time around. If it helps, the cursor in that terminal window changes from flashing to solid on occasion, and ps -a shows that there are dkms processes running.

Comment: Update: Turns out I had the xorg hwe package installed, and reverting that back to the GA one let the image appear to finish. Will report back with final success.

Comment: Success. Had to kill apt-get when reinstalling the headers, but then running the reconfigure command it spits out let it finish, and 4.18.0-15 is now successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

See the same problem when deploying Bionics with FAI. The initrd is not generated when installing HWE kernels. As a workaround after installing the HWE packages I also manually create initrd with

```
update-initramfs -c -k `ls -1 /lib/modules/ | head -2 | tail -1`
update-grub
```

It suppose to take the latest kernel version from /lib/modules..