# Ubuntu 18.04 on Macbook hangs *EVERY time in desktop environment

Tags: dual-boot, macbook

I'm a total noob with Ubuntu installed on a partition on my mid-2009 Macbook as a dual-boot, no rEFInd, just booting in by holding down Option key and choosing EFI Boot when I want to.

Some basic system stats:

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M GPU

Broadcom Bluetooth Chipset

RAM: 6 GB DDR2 800 MHz SDRAM

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo (2.13 GHz), 2 cores, L2: 3MB

Hard drive: Samsung 1 TB (~493 GB for Ubuntu, ~6 GB swap, rest Mac OS). Old school HD, not solid state.

My Mac OS version is El Capitan, 10.11.6

Every time I try to use my Ubuntu, it ends up hanging, where I can move the mouse cursor, no clicks, no keyboard response, just cursor movement. I pretty much always boot up and log in just fine, the trouble happens either almost immediately after I get to the Desktop, or soon afterwards, I don't think I've ever had an Ubuntu session that lasted more than 20 minutes before this occurred, if even that. Haven't yet gotten a chance to really try any diagnostic techniques because this is my second install and it still has me go through the Welcome stuff when I log in. Had to reinstall bc I forgot my original password, I stopped messing with my 1st install when I reached the point of "Ok, I may as well stick to MacOS bc I really need my computer to just g**d*** WORK instead of me fiddling around & hard rebooting 5 times a day".

Now, though, it just seems to get worse. I can't even try to install the NVIDIA driver before the hang occurs. I had that done the first time around, but it didn't help.

I don't know how much it matters, but I do have a swap partition of about 5.87 GB (as accurate as I could do with El Capitan's Disk Utility). My first Ubuntu, I didn't have a swap partition.

Another thing I'll mention, relevant or not, is that I don't seem to have a working Recovery Disk on the MAC OS side (but I have a OS X installer on a thumb drive), possibly because it's a replacement HD.

I have tried to research the problem, but I can't seem to find anything relevant to my circumstances, all the threads I find on something like this are very old for previous versions, or are incomprehensible for a newb like me, or suggest fixes relying on the keyboard (for freeze issues), which I can't do because my keyboard won't work when this happens, or are from users who have this issue when trying to boot, and they can't even get to the desktop.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions y'all can give, even if it's just a nudge in the direction of diagnosing. I'm sure there's more diagnostics that would need to be done, but please bear in mind I'm very green at this, so if you can provide commands and/or links to relevant pages, or "if/else/then scenarios, that would be very helpful. Suggesting I "try checking your memory logs", or something along those lines is almost meaningless to me at this point, because 1, I don't really know how, and 2, I don't really know what I'd be looking for or what I should do if I find "it".

Maybe I'm asking a lot there with just a little to go on, but I'll be keeping an eye on this thread in the next few days and will respond relatively quickly as I'm on vacation right now, so I'll be happy to respond to further questions and/or post output to commands and such if my computer allows me to. Thank you all, and wish me luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm happy to report that my issue seems more or less resolved (I say more or less, because I have experienced one more hang). It took patience and persistence, and maybe a little luck, but here's what I did...

1. I made installing the NVIDIA drivers my number one priority.

   It took several tries (hard reboots), but every time I logged into Ubuntu, I tried to install the NVIDIA and Broadcom drivers. This is well documented on the web, but just for completion's sake, I went the GUI route and opened Software & Updates>Additional Drivers.
2. After that was done, and I honestly don't remember at this point if it was during the same session, I wanted to wait a couple days and see if I got a response on this forum, and/or could find a fix on my own before I posted further... I opened up Terminal and ran the following, as one continuous line with spaces included:

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04

Apologies, I don't yet know how to do the nice-and-neat box thing, I may update that later. I originally found this on Medium at https://medium.com/@gspasov2/how-to-fix-ubuntu-18-04-lts-random-freezes-52bb75d55c70, but the line as shown there didn't work for me (I think it's a webpage rendering problem), so I found the correct line on [Cannot fully install hwe stack on 18.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119872/cannot-fully-install-hwe-stack-on-18-04-2)  when I Paste it into a web search. Thanks, Sergei, Brandon, and AskUbuntu community!

Luckily, I didn't seem to have the same issues that Brandon had, I restarted eventually and ran my first long Ubuntu session, and things have been working pretty smoothly so far, even with restarts, boots between different OS sessions, etc. Like I mentioned, I did have a hang yesterday, but no OS is perfect, and I had several flawless Ubuntu sessions before that one, so I think it's okay now, but I'll update if I start seeing the problem again soon.

So, my takeaways on this:

- The installation of drivers appropriate for your hardware (graphics and networking) should probably be a number one priority after installation and successful booting. I don't think that alone made the ultimate difference in my case, but what I've gathered on many forums and articles seems to support this.
- If the system freezes or hangs, you may have to reboot several times and simply wait and hope for the time where you can keep it going long enough to get to where you can install your drivers and apply any other fixes, possibly including the line
  above which ultimately seems to have helped me and at least 2 other people. I know, waiting and hoping for that moment doesn't sound reassuring and in practice is excruciating. Give yourself and your system a chance to rest if you keep having issues.
- Related to the last point, I theorize that Ubuntu has to "register" that you've finished the Welcome portion completely before you may get to a point where it will remain stable enough for you to install the drivers and run that command. The first several times in my case was where the system would hang.
- If you're even reading this, you're hopefully either taking the same approach, or if you're not, it may be too late, but in my opinion, it's HIGHLY advisable to either keep a partition with your previous OS (with backups on an external drive), or have a second, stable computer to work with until you can get your Ubuntu running stably. That's just a noob's word to other noobs, and I'm sure I'll be asking noob questions for a while, but since no one else so far has added to this thread, I'll say that just to hope anyone may find it helpful.

There's the virtual machine option, of course, but I personally can't advise on the ins and outs of that yet, since I didn't try that here.

I know I've been lengthy here, and for more experienced Linux users, I bet much or all of what I've written here may sound trite and amateurish, which I'm sure it is, but I'm here to learn, and I welcome any feedback, corrections, or additional info. Just hope that someone will find this heplful.